# 1000Mbps RGMII and 100Mbps PHY

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, arm

An ARM SoC (Amlogic S905) indicates that the ethernet is 1000Mbps RGMII and 100Mbps PHY.

Does that mean that the communication with the physical layer is slow?

Comment: Can you link to where exactly you read that? arm SoCs don't usually have integrated phys

Comment: @PeterGreen http://linux-meson.com/